# Android - Child order in Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm writing a custom `ViewGroup` which is a simple combination of other views. However, the Views seem to be in arbitrary order.

I know I can implement the `getChildDrawingOrder()` method but I was curious how the order of the Views was determined in the first place ?

---

**UPDATE:** This is a minimum implementation and it works but I don't know why the indicator is always on top no matter what I do

```
public class PaginatedGallery extends ViewGroup {

ViewPager mPager;
CirclePageIndicator mPagerIndicator;

public PaginatedGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mPager = new ViewPager(context);
    mPagerIndicator = new CirclePageIndicator(context);
    addView(mPager);
    addView(mPagerIndicator);
}

public void setAdapter(PaginatedGalleryAdapter adapter) {
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPagerIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int count = getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i< count; i++ ) {
        getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
    }

}   
}
```

I know I'm not implementing `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` is just plain vanilla but I'm just curious as to why indicator is the first child and not the pager.

Comment: put your code here.... so I can guess exactly what you want...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The Views are simply called in the order that they were added to the parent.

In my case, one View was above the other on the Z-axis whereas I was thinking that it was above the other on the Y-axis but that's because the Pager has an empty space at the top where the Indicator was seemingly fitting.

Stupid mistake !!